# How to rotate whole table in Pages document?

Tags: pages

Is there any way to rotate a table by 90 degree? I've got vertical document but one table is to wide so I would like to rotate it.

Answer (score 3):

> Rotate an image, shape, text box, line, arrow, or video Select the
>   object, then in the Format  sidebar, click the Arrange tab.
>
> Drag the Rotate wheel, or enter a degree value in the adjacent field
>   to specify the angle at which you want to rotate the object.
>
> Tip: You can also press the **Command key while your pointer is over a
>   white square on the object, then drag to rotate**.

Source: [Pages for Mac: Resize, rotate, and flip objects in a Pages document](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23667?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it but it's locked. https://imgur.com/a/KRkeZ

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have tried. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

1. Insert a shape near the table and change the fill to 'No Fill'
2. Select the shape and the table
3. Group the shape and table together
4. Rotate the group

If you ungroup the elements the table will revert back to the original rotation, but you can still resize etc the table from within the group.

Answer (score 0):

Can’t try this to be sure as I am on a smartphone, but a possibilty is to insert a section break before and after and the change the page orientation to landscape.